# How to insert value for bit column of mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to insert the value into a bit type column in MySQL. But I am getting a data truncation error.

```
CREATE TABLE `BITTESTTABLE` (
  `db_field` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   `is_editable` bit(1) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

If I am inserting a row with

`INSERT INTO BITTESTTABLE values('XYZ','0')`

I am getting

> Data too long for column 'is_editable' at row 1

So how do I insert the data for bit type column?

Comment: change to `INSERT INTO BITTESTTABLE values('XYZ',0);` inserting the number 0 not the character..

Comment: Integer type data it takes perfectly even though I use quotes for the data like '123' but why bits type is not taking is there any restriction in MySQL?

Comment: if you will put like '123' it means it will take like string and Integer is support to null value and null value is also string

Comment: @SrinivasDJ, if you will insert integer value '123' sometime it works because of sql tools or query but if you will insert ineteger value like 'abc' the it will throw error.......sql workbench, yog tools supports integer '123' cause of conversation of tools

Comment: I recommend using a TINYINT instead of a BIT. Your DBAL should quote and escape every value, so you'll have single quotes, which will work fine for a TINYINT, but not for a BIT.

Comment: @Piyush I have inserted a row without using any sql tools ( workbench, yog etc)  if you give 'abc' instead of '123' of a integer column value we will  get an error "incorrect integer value" so it means internally it converts to the string to integer. You are saying "sometimes" it will work so is there any version restrictions for mysql?

Comment: @SrinivasDJ, you are right. I tried without tool. Its means it converts internally.

Answer (score 37):

You should use:

```
INSERT INTO `BITTESTTABLE` VALUES('XYZ', b'0');
```

Comment: Worked for entering directly into the MySQL Workbench grid.

Answer (score 8):

Since bit is a number not a string you need enter it like

```
INSERT INTO BITTESTTABLE values('XYZ',0)
```

Comment: Suppose if I have interger data type if I insert column value as '123' mysql accepts. it won't give an error.

Comment: Oh thanks for telling me this. Once I was adding  number like this '1' in Int column it gives me error!

Answer (score 6):

You need to insert data in bit format like this `INSERT INTO BITTESTTABLE values('XYZ',0);`.you are doing `values('XYZ','0')` so it is taking as string value.

Answer (score 5):

You can use true/false directly; BUT I am not sure if this is related to MySQL itself or to InnoDB : 
EXAMPLE:

```
INSERT INTO BITTESTTABLE values('XYZ',false);    
INSERT INTO BITTESTTABLE values('XYZ',true);
```

To be sure try to run:

```
SELECT TRUE , FALSE  ;
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, for `boolean` or `bit` data types, you would use 0 or 1 like that:

```
INSERT INTO BITTESTTABLE values('XYZ',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem inserting data in prostgres db and I resolved.

Do like this
INSERT INTO table (bitData)
VALUES (CAST(1 AS bit));

rather then
INSERT INTO table (bitData)
VALUES (1);